# Python thread is not threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been looking all over google and can't seem to get this working.
I'm trying to thread 2 functions, both of which are infinite loops.

Looking at the extract below, it only starts the 1st thread and does not proceed to the next one in line.

PS: When I swap the 2 threads around, then I have the same problem with the 2nd thread.

```
def syslog_service():
    syslog_server = socketserver.UDPServer((syslog_host,syslog_port), Syslog_Server)
    syslog_server.serve_forever()

def cleanup_old_logs_service():
#   lock = threading.Lock()
#   threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    global syslog_retention_hours
    global RUNNING
    while RUNNING:
#       cleanup_old_logs_service.lock.acquire()
        cleanup.old_logs(syslog_retention_hours)
#       cleanup_old_logs_service.lock.release() 
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logger.info("Starting main thread")
        config()
        logger.info("Starting system testing")
        test()
        logger.info("Config loaded")
        thread1 = cleanup_old_logs_service()
        thread2 = syslog_service()
        thread1.start()
        logger.info("Syslog cleanup service running")
        thread2.start()
        logger.info("Syslog server running")
```

Comment: Calling a variable `thread1` doesn't automatically make it a thread. You don't actually make any threads here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only the first thread is executed is that you actually have ONLY one thread in your program. When you write `thread1 = cleanup_old_logs_service()` and `thread2 = syslog_service()`you are not creating new threads, but just assigning the return values of your functions to 2 different variables. For this reason, as soon as the program encounters `thread1`, it executes `cleanup_old_logs_service()` and gets stuck in an infinite loop.

To create a new thread, I would import the `threading` module, create a new `threadObj` object and start the thread as follows:

```
import threading

threadObj = threading.Thread(target=cleanup_old_logs_service)
threadObj.start()
```

This way, the function `cleanup_old_logs_service()` will be executed in a new thread.

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

By saying `thread1 = cleanup_old_logs_service()` you are actually executing the function `cleanup_old_logs_service` not saving a reference to a thread. You would have to say

```
import threading # If you have not already

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=cleanup_old_logs_service)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=syslog_service)

# Now you can start the thread
thread1.start()
logger.info("Syslog cleanup service running")
thread2.start()
logger.info("Syslog server running")
```

You can look at https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html for documentation and https://pymotw.com/2/threading/ for examples, because I believe you would need to use `locks` to manage access to your resources